# How to proof with the definition of gamma function?

Tags: analysis, gamma-function

$\Gamma(\dfrac{1}{2}-z)\Gamma(\dfrac{1}{2}+z) = \dfrac{\pi}{cos \pi z}$

thanks for the comment
this problem has been solved

Comment: yes i have, but cant reach the final result. would you mind to give me some hint? which way do i have to take to solve this problem?

Comment: @megapangastuti Well for starters, plugging in the definition of the gamma function might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the well-known Euler's reflection formula, namely,

\begin{equation}
\Gamma{(z)}\Gamma{(1 - z)} = \dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}.
\end{equation}

Taking $z = \frac{1}{2} - z$ yields the equation that you are looking for.

The proof for Euler's reflective equation is given here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula

Comment: I prefer the opposite direction : it is not hard to show $\Gamma{(s)}\Gamma{(1 - s)} - \dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ is a $2$-periodic and bounded entire function, [thus constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), and looking at $s=0$ or $s=1/2$ it is $=0$. From this we get $\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = \gamma - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ quite easily, using Liouville again, thus the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(s)$.